# Remove "Server" header from response header in Cherrypy

Tags: cherrypy

I am trying to remove the "Server" header from the response.header in Cherrypy via a Custom Tool that I have written. I have hooked this tool to "before_finalize" hook point.

```
class ChangeHeadersTool(cherrypy.Tool):
    def __init__(self):
        cherrypy.Tool.__init__(self, 'before_finalize',
                               self.remove_headers,
                               priority=100)

    def remove_headers(self):
        cherrypy.response.headers.pop('Server', None)
```

The tool is working fine. All the responses are passed through the tool and I am able to pop out other headers from the response. But the 'Server' header getsa added back somewhere down the line I guess. Is there any other way to remove the 'Server' header from the tool

Comment: I tried this and it is working fine. https://stackoverflow.com/a/15035521/381786